# How to use scala actor based event sourcing app from another language (python)

Tags: scala, akka, zeromq

I'm somewhat familiar with scala and less familiar with akka, although I know what actor models is (the idea seems quite simple).

So let's say that right now this is my code (in reality what I need is event sourcing application). I need to be able to use it from any language, not just from JVM.

So of course I googled about that and I've found [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/zeromq.html). The problem with that is that If my understanding is correct I would need to create some custom protocol, deserialization and dispatching for zmq messages and that is totally uncool. Maybe there exists solution for that already? If not, than how to do that in most efficient way? Maybe I need to create some message case classes and something like facade actor that would do deserialization?

```
class HelloActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("well, helllo!")
    case _ => println("huh?")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor")
  helloActor ! "hello"
  helloActor ! "buenos dias"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, depends on the protocol you are using ect. For a language specific way is you can use [Pyro](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4). Just like java, you can serialize generic objects in python and then transfer them over the network, which you can use Pyro for. You can take advantage of the fact that python is implemented on both the jvm (Jython), and natively. Not sure if its a great idea to write this just in scala and python, I would create the API in java, and then add that to the scala classpath, then any other JVM language can also use your API. In addition it's more common to use jython with java so there are other benifits that come with being the majority.

But anway the common language that the jvm and python will understand will be these serialized python objects. So what you will need to know is:

- How to use jython with java
- How to use pyro

And yea using scala with jython is only a matter of adding the jars to the classpath, as you probably already know.

**EDIT:** Ok I think I might not have made this method clear enough. So basically:
JVM uses jython to create a jython instance, which is sent to a remote python object. The communication is done with the module Pyro. This program can send serialized python objects back as well.

This is what happens normally with remote actors in java, except the messages are implementing Serializable. Python and Java are not in the same process, or using native methods, or anything like that. They can be on the same machine or different machines. This method is not platform specific.

Hopefully this method is usefull to someone.

Comment: No, surely no Jython. For one thing there is no numpy in Jython.
I've found that akka-zeromq still uses zmq 2.0 and AFAIK doens't work with zmq 3.0. This is really sucks, because zmq is in 4.0 for about half a year. So no zeromq, and probably no scala for me...

Comment: Yeah, I've read your post. I'm not seeking for a language specific way. I want language agnostic way. I don't want to rely on JMS or something. Right now I'm thinking about using http as transport... Maybe I can create actor that would listen http connection and deserialize events from json representation. What do you think about that?

Comment: Yeah everybody loves Json these days. I'm not massively knowledgeable on protocols. But anyway my answer wasn’t telling you to use Jython as a means to implement your program, but only for a communication between the JVM and CPython. It really depends what messages you are going to be sending I would say. The benefit with serializing jvm or python objects is that you can simply cast them and inspect them ect, but may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to use Jython as communication layer beetween JVM and CPython. Unless you're talking about additional layer of indirection where I would make inter-process call from actual python app to some translator app that is using Jython. Seems like a dirty hack. Anyway, the question in not about python, but about language agnostic way. Sorry, If that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Akka actor solution was a little bit overkill, so I end up implementing my own event sourcing solution in this open source project.

The persistence layer is a decision for the developer, but I provide practical examples of execution using couchbase.

Take a look in case you consider useful.

https://github.com/politrons/Scalaydrated